# how to make a combobox visible upon selecting on another combobox in php?

Tags: php, combobox

I have two combobox. I made the second one hidden and I want to make the second combobox visible after I select one from the first combobox.

Comment: by using javascript or jquery you can do it....

Comment: Can you share or give me a sample code? Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>

<select id="second_combo_box_id" style="visibility:hidden;" >
  <option value="">Select a option:</option>
  <option value="1">value 1</option>
  <option value="2">value 2</option>

  </select>


 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>

function showUser(str) {

    $('#second_combo_box_id').css("visibility", "visible");
}
</script>
```